# Search within Mysql with special chars

Tags: mysql, search

If I have a table `files` and it has a column `title`, and some of the titles are in this format:

```
google: and facebook
stack: overflow
```

Now I'm trying to add search functionality in my app, which executes              a `LIKE '%word%'` query. But if people search `google and facebook` it doesn't find anything, unless they specifically search for `google: and facebook`.
I know what `LIKE` does and why it doesn't give the results I'm looking for, I'm just asking if there's a way to search in mysql table and ignoring special chars like `: ' - . , "` etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Use REPLACE function prior to comparison. ... REPLACE( fieldname, ':', '') LIKE %word%

Comment: You should post your question more clearly, user doesn't know what your data exactly like, even you ignoring special chars, they may type one more blank like 'google   and facebook  ' or without 'and' like 'google facebook'. So even `replace` or `REGEXP` can give what you now want, but you also never know what a user will type to search.

Comment: I know, I just asked specifically about special characters because I face this problem many times.

Comment: @smozgur As for now, your solution works pretty fine for me. So if you'd like you can write this as an answer and I"ll accept. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should use full-text searching instead of `LIKE`. This will allow them to search for `google facebook`, they wouldn't have to include `and`.

Comment: Maybe a better question is why you have the titles in that format in the first place?

Comment: Honestly it might cause slow query in large datasets but I use it a lot as a quick workaround. Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REPLACE function prior to comparison.

```
... REPLACE( fieldname, ':', '') LIKE %word%
```

Comment: Thanks. 
As you said, this doesn't fit for large data-sets, but in my case it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with regular expressions

[MYSQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Why does he need 5.7 or higher? MySQL has had regular expressions for a long time.

Comment: It would be better if you showed an example of how he could change his `LIKE` to the appropriate regexp.

Comment: Then he is using the expression i made for him and tomorrow he needs an other one, because he finds more problems and asks again :) I think it is not our work to give the TO an answer on the silver plate, but to show him the tools he can solve his problem with.

Comment: I'm afraid that just pointing him to the documentation, without any guidance or examples, will not help him at all.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff   
Thank you for your help, but I have to agree with Barmar, for the sake of those who would look for the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to replace all spaces in the search string with '%' or you explode the search string (space as separater) and connect the different parts with an OR statement.